# Concatenate forward and reversed vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm looking for the recommended way, in C++, to make a new `std::vector` where the first half of the vector is the contents of another vector, and the second half is the reversed contents of that other vector. To do something like this in a scripting language such as Matlab . . .

```
A = [2; 4; 6; 8;];
B = [A; flipud(A)];
```

This would be easy to do in C++ using loops, but I'm wondering if there is a neater way using `insert` and perhaps a reverse itterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can use `insert` and `reverse_iterator`s:

```
auto B = A;
B.insert(B.end(), A.rbegin(), A.rend());
```

You can of course also reserve the space before the first assignment to only have one allocation, as you please. But I think the idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> A = {8, 2, 4, 5, 2};

std::vector<int> B(A);
B.insert(B.end(), A.rbegin(), A.rend());
```